# Assign value of environment variable to another variable in .env file

Tags: bash, docker-compose

I define a variable in an `.env` file:

```
LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
```

When using this in the following `docker-compose.yml` I can see that the variable is expanded to `127.0.0.1` by running `docker-compose config`.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  my-service:
    environment:
      # This gets expanded to http://127.0.0.1/services
      SERVICE_ENDPOINT: http://${LOCAL_IP}/services
```

Now I'd like to reference the value of `LOCAL_IP` in another variable in the same file like:

```
LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
SOME_OTHER_VAR=$LOCAL_IP
```

**Updated docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  my-service:
    environment:
      SERVICE_ENDPOINT: http://${SOME_OTHER_VAR}/services
```

Running `docker-compose config` then gives me:

```
services:
  my-service:
    environment:
      # I'd have expected http://127.0.0.1/services
      SERVICE_ENDPOINT: http://$$LOCAL_IP:8090/services
```

Comment: Yes, of course. Have you not tried it before asking this question?

Comment: I tried as shown in my question but the point is that it does not seem to work. That's why I have asked. I upadted my question to make things a bit clearer.

Comment: FYI you're not crazy @RobertStrauch. I'm also having difficulty getting `docker-compose` to respect definitions inside .env like `VAR_FOR_DOCKER_COMPOSE=$SOME_OTHER_ENV_VAR`. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @RobertStrauch Did you try runnning the `env` command to check first that the value of `SOME_OTHER_VAR` is indeed `127.0.0.1`?